# What template was used to create my PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database that I think was create using a custom template database.

Is there a way to see what template was used to create the database? There doesn't seem to be any documentation that describes this.

Comment: It is hard to prove a negative but it is not in the pg_database catalog table nor does pgAdmin specify it when it shows the create statement for a database. If you really need to know you will have to test for the existence or lack thereof for certain objects it would have copied from the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, no, there is no system catalogue that tracks this. I'm not sure it would be terribly useful to know that database "X" was created from "template2" unless you could prove exactly what the contents of "template2" were at the point of copying. If you're tracking things to that level of detail then you will already have the creation logged.